# AppDrawer Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget Error Flutter

Tags: flutter

I don´t know what is wrong here. I am trying to do a drawer in flutter. This is my code:

```
String userName = "";
  String userEmail = "";

  @override
  initState() {
    getUserNameAndEmail();
    super.initState();
  }

  getUserNameAndEmail() async {
    await HelperFunctions.getUserNameInSharedPreference().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        userName = value;
      });
    });
    await HelperFunctions.getUserEmailInSharedPreference().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        userEmail = value;
      });
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final displayName = userName;
    final displayEmail = userEmail;
    final image = 'assets/images/woman.png';
    return Drawer(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: AppColors.verdementa),
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  buildHeader(
                      image: image,
                      name: truncateWithEllipsis(10, displayName),
                      email: displayEmail,
                      onClicked: () => selectedItem(context, 4)),
                  const SizedBox(height: 8),
                  buildMenuItem(
                    text: 'Home',
                    icon: Icons.house,
                    onClicked: () => selectedItem(context, 0),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 8),
                  buildMenuItem(
                    text: 'Diário do sono',
                    icon: Icons.bed,
                    onClicked: () => selectedItem(context, 1),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 8),
                  buildMenuItem(
                    text: 'Leituras',
                    icon: Icons.book_online,
                    onClicked: () => selectedItem(context, 2),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 8),
                  buildMenuItem(
                    text: 'Questionários',
                    icon: Icons.list_alt,
                    onClicked: () => selectedItem(context, 3),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 8),
                  buildMenuItem(
                    text: 'Contatos',
                    icon: Icons.people,
                    onClicked: () => selectedItem(context, 4),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

After click to open the drawer I get a lot of exceptions like this:

```
**════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 320 pos 12: 'width > 0.0': is not true.
box.dart:320
The relevant error-causing widget was
FittedBox
AppDrawer.dart:197
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFittedBox#859fa relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was
Container
AppDrawer.dart:195
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#29950 relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was
Column
═══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.
Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a RepaintBoundary widget.
The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
  Column ← Expanded ← RepaintBoundary ← IndexedSemantics ← _SelectionKeepAlive ← NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← KeepAlive ← AutomaticKeepAlive ← KeyedSubtree ← SliverList ← ⋯
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack**
```

If I use:

```
final displayName = "someName";
final displayEmail = "someEmail";
```

it works fine!

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `Expanded` widget. It means that the child of this widget should occupy all remaining space within the parent, therefore the parent must be a widget that has a fixed size. Otherwise it has no meaning to "occupy the rest of the available space".

For example if you have a `Row` with full width, you can add the first child and wrap the second child into `Expanded`. As a result it will fill the remaining space.

In your case, `Expanded` is within a `ListView` which has no fixed height.

The solution is to remove `Expanded`, and the error will stop to show. In fact, you can also remove the `Column` and add the children directly to the `ListView`. Or you can remove the `ListView` and keep the existing `Column` and wrap it into a `SingleChildScrollView` if the contents might require scrolling.

Comment: I remove the Expanded and the Column but I got an error that does not show nothing in the debug console. It opens errors_patch.dart and show:@pragma("vm:external-name", "AssertionError_throwNew")
  external static _doThrowNew(
      int assertionStart, int assertionEnd, Object? message);

Comment: If I try to change the ListView for the Column the same error appear

Comment: It must be something else, I tried your Drawer with the modifications I wrote and it worked. Another issue can be that you mix `await` with `.then`. Try to call `getUserNameInSharedPreference` and the other simply with await without .then, and in the next line setState.

Comment: Look If I change String userName = ""; String userEmail = ""; with some values, like String userName = "A";  String userEmail = "A"; It works fine. It looks like I need to start with a value that is not empty string to capture some space to render.